# Como pasar la ruta de un archivo por medio de ajax usando FileUpload de asp,net c#

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net, fileupload

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema. Estoy leyendo un archivo de `excel` y ahora intento obtener la dirección completa de mi archivo `excel` del lado del cliente para pasar la ruta como parámetro en mi `ajax` y este a mi `webmethod` y así poder mostrar los datos en mi `grid(jqxGrid)`.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Este es mi `WebMethod`

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string Importar_Excel(string path)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ExcelToDataTable(path);
        string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
        return datos;

    }
```

Este es mi código donde obtengo los datos del `excel` y lo convierto a `DataTable` con `epplus`.

```
 public static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string path)
    {
        using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            bool hasHeader = true; 
            foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
            }
            var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
            for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
            {
                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                var row = tbl.NewRow();
                foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                {
                    row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                }
                tbl.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return tbl;

        }
    }
```

Este es el código de mi `ajax` donde yo pretendo obtener la dirección del archivo y mandarla como parámetro.

```js
function obtener_datosExcel() {

var path = $("#fuImportarArchivo").val();

  var valores;
        var datafields = new Array();
        var columns = new Array();
        var columnsArray = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "frmCompensaciones.aspx/Importar_Excel",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{path:"' + path + '"}', //Aqui es donde intento enviar la ruta
            async: false,

            success: function(data) {

                if (data != '') {


                    valores = data.d;                    
                    valores = JSON.parse(valores[0]);

                    for (var i in valores[0]) {
                        datafields.push({ name: i });
                        columns.push({ text: i, datafield: i, width: 200 });

                    }

                    for (var j = 1; j < columns_bonos.length; j++) {
                        columnsArray.push(columns_bonos[j]);

                    }

                }
}
```

Comment: Estas diciendo que el usuario que esta del lado del cliente utilizara un fileupload para selecionar un archivo local de su maquina y luego pasar la ruta de ese archivo al servidor y que el servidor lea ese archivo.

Comment: Hola @OrlandoDeLaRosa si es lo que pretendo hacer ya que quiero mostrar los datos en un jqxGrid y este solo trabaja con ajax. ¿Existe alguna otra solución que me puedas proporcionar?

Comment: Y si la ruta del cliente no existe del lado del servidor ni tampoco el documento? como lo vas a leer?. Creo que lo que nesecitas hacer es un upload completo del documento y despues procesar y colocarlo en tu grilla.

Comment: Por motivos de seguridad, el explorador no puede enviar la url del fileupload, te mostrará a lo mas FILE://FAKEPATH/nombredetuarchivo.xlsx, si deseas leer el archivo, tienes que subirlo.

Comment: Claro, como comenta Orlando, esa variable path que tienes en tu web method deberia tomar el path del archivo una ves subido a tu servidor, en tal caso deberias primero crear un metodo para enviar el archivo al server, este devolveria un path o un codigo de path, al cliente y luego el cliente llamaria a tu primer webmethod con estos datos.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Ok te entiendo muy bien tendrás algún ejemplo de como hacer el upload completo, ya que el archivo lo puedo leer desde el codebehind y mostrarlo en un Gridview de asp.net pero no se como enviar los datos ya que el WebMethod no acepta controles. Gracias.

Comment: Hola @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver, los entiendo muy bien en el  codebehind he guardado este archivo en una carpeta con el codigo SaveAs(Ubicacion del archivo). Esto puedo hacerlo en el codebehind sin usar ajax lo que no puedo hacer es colocarlo dentro del WebMethod ya que este no acepta controles al ser static.

Comment: Hola @Luciano Montañez, los entiendo muy bien en el codebehind he guardado este archivo en una carpeta con el codigo SaveAs(Ubicacion del archivo). Esto puedo hacerlo en el codebehind sin usar ajax lo que no puedo hacer es colocarlo dentro del WebMethod ya que este no acepta controles al ser static.

Comment: Si ya tienes forma de leer el documento, entonces en el webmothod devuelves un json con la informacion que procesaste y se lo asignas a la grilla con jqxGrid para jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente primer paso el usuario sube el archivo y al presionar un boton ese archivo lo guardas del lado del servidor.

En tu html agregas la libreria de jquery

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

en el cuerpor de tu pagina:

```
   <input type="file" id="file1"  />  
   <input id="btnPostFile" type="button" value="Guardar archivo" />
```

en la parte de tu script declara

```
  $('#btnPostFile').click(function () {  
                    if ($('#file1').val() == '') {  
                        alert('selecciona archivo');  
                        return;  
                    }  

                    var formData = new FormData();  
                    var file = $('#file1')[0];  
                    formData.append('file', file.files[0]);  
                    $.ajax({  
                        url: 'http://tuServido/GuardarExcel',  
                        type: 'POST',  
                        data: formData,  
                        contentType: false,  
                        processData: false,  
                        success: function (d) {  
                            alert('archivo guardado')
                        },  
                        error: function () {  
                           alert('revisar error');
                        }  
                    });  
                });
```

Por ultimo en tu metodo del lado del servidor guardas el archivo:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GuardarExcel()  
        {  
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;  
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;  
           if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)  
            {  
                var docfiles = new List<string>();  
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)  
                {  
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];  
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);  
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);  
                    docfiles.Add(filePath);  
                }  
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);  
            }  
             return result;  
        }
```

Nota1: EL codigo agregado es para darte una guia, debes ajustar el valor de tus variablesa y metodo de guardado.