# Como crear un WebMethod a partir de dos métodos donde uno de ellos no es static

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Hola amigos otra vez de vuelta con una nueva pregunta espero me puedan ayudar de antemano gracias.

Tengo dos métodos para leer un excel con epplus. Todo funciona de maravilla pero por ahora quiero programar un WebMethod con estos dos métodos para enviarlos por ajax y mostrar la información en un Grid(jqxGrid).

Mi pregunta seria ¿Como programar este WebMethod? ¿Como tendria que ser mi ajax?

Este es mi codigo para obtener el archivo con FileUpload

```
public string ruta() //Como se puede ver no es de tipo static
    {
        string fileName="";
        string fileExtension="";
        string fileLocation="";
        if (fuImportarArchivo.HasFile)
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(fuImportarArchivo.FileName);
            fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fuImportarArchivo.FileName);
            fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Excel/" + fileName);
            fuImportarArchivo.SaveAs(fileLocation);

        }
        return fileLocation;

    }
```

Este es mi otro método donde le paso como parámetro la ruta o resultado del método anterior

```
   public static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string path)
    {
        using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            bool hasHeader = true; 
            foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
            }
            var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
            for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
            {
                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                var row = tbl.NewRow();
                foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                {
                    row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                }
                tbl.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return tbl;

        }
    }
```

Aqui es donde trato de crear mi WebMethod

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string Importar_Excel()
    {
        string dir_archivo = ruta(); //Aqui me muestra error mi metodo ---> Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, metodo o propiedad no estaticos.
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ExcelToDataTable(dir_archivo);
        string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
        return datos;           
    }
```

Comment: El metodo `ruta()` debes de declararlo como estatico. Deberia quedar asi: `public static string ruta()`.

Comment: Hola @OrlandoDeLaRosa inicialmente hice eso pero ahi ocupo mi control UploadFile llamado fuImportarArchivo lo cual al poner static mi metodo estos me marcan error. ¿Podrias darme alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Create una clase de utilidad donde te creas un metodo estatico y como parametro de ese nuevo metodo estatico le pasas como a `fuImportarArchivo`

Comment: Pregunta, en que momento creas o le pasas un valor a `fuImportarArchivo`?

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Los valores se los paso aqui. fuImportarArchivo.SaveAs(fileLocation);

Comment: no entiendo el contexto, `ruta()` como lo invocas? porque hacer un upload por el fileUpload requiere de un evento de la pagina que realice el submit del form, en cambio la llamada ajax va por otro camino

Comment: Hola @LeandroTuttini la pregunta del OP esta relacionada con la [pregunta anterior que iso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/249296/107347). A mi parecer se esta enredando o complicando con el `webmethod` y el `HttpContext.Current.Request.File`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La unica forma que se me ocurre es desacoplando las acciones

Por un lado tienes el upload del archivo que se realiza en el submit del form, imagino en algun eventos

```
public void btnUpload_Click(...)
{
    //resto codigo
    string fileLocation = ruta();

    Session["fileLocation"] = fileLocation;
}
```

Entonces conservas la ruta en `Session` para usarla en el tro paso

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Importar_Excel()
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.Session["fileLocation"] == null)
    {
        //aqui deberias devolver algun mensaje
        return "";
    }

    string dir_archivo = HttpContext.Current.Session["fileLocation"].ToString();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ExcelToDataTable(dir_archivo);
    string datos = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
    return datos;           
}
```

Es alli donde lo recuperas accediendo al `HttpContext.Current` tomando la ruta donde se dejo el archivo

Para subir un archivo sin refrescar la pagina se podria aplicar esta tecnica

[Upload File without Form Submit (PostBack) using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-File-without-Form-Submit-PostBack-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: Hola @Leandro Tuttini he probado el código y me funciono de maravilla solo una pregunta mas ¿Existe algún modo de llamar al método ruta() sin tener que meterlo dentro del botón? Ya que actualmente tengo 2 botones y pensaba solo tener uno en caso de que se pudiera. Gracias.

Comment: Se podria ver de hacer usando ajax con el link que puse al final de la edicion de la respuesta